# Bootstrap change column number at breakpoints

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble with a layout I'm producing. I am dealing with blocks of content that are generated from my database, so I'm essentially ending up with:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    ... etc
```

The problem is, as the columns are floated they are ending up stacking on top of each other in the event that one has more content than the other.

I know that technically I should be using rows like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 record"></div>
```

Except, obviously, on larger screens I need to have three elements per row.

Is there a way around this or a CSS rule I can add to clear the floated elements and keep everything lining up at both the lg and sm breakpoint?

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/RWoMmM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add something like this:

```
/* On medium screens, clear every 2 elements starting at 3rd element */
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px){
  .row > div:nth-child(2n+3){
    clear: both;
  }
}

/* On large screens, clear every 3 elements starting at 4th element */
@media(min-width: 1200px){
  .row > div:nth-child(3n+4){
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly the sort of thing I was after! Thanks